# Why does this resolve the type to the interface?

Tags: java, generics

I tried to implement generic `max(a, b)` method for `Object`s, that implement `Comparable` as follows:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T o1, T o2) {
    return o1.compareTo(o2) >= 0 ? o1 : o2;
}
```

It works for, e.g. `String`, but for `java.time.LocalDate`, the type parameter resolves to `ChronoLocalDate` and I cannot figure out why:

```
LocalDate date1 = ..., date2 = ...;
LocalDate ld = CompareUtils.max(date1, date2); // compile error here
```

The error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChronoLocalDate to LocalDate". How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the values of `date1` and `date2`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I needed to add `? super T` to the type parameter declaration:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T o1, T o2) {
    return o1.compareTo(o2) >= 0 ? o1 : o2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> for `java.time.LocalDate`, the type parameter resolves to `ChronoLocalDate` and I cannot figure out why

This happens because `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` (as opposed to `Comparable<LocalDate>`).

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> ```
> Serializable, Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>, ...
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I actually found the solution by chance.